# How do I add my output of max and min together to get the sum

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

How do I add my output of max and min together to get the sum in `sql` query.

Below my query:

```
SELECT max(marks) AS max,
       min(marks) AS min 
  FROM students 
 (SELECT SUM(MIN(marks), MAX(marks)) FROM student
```

Comment: pls tel me ..i m the beginner

Comment: Provide more information regarding the sample data what is your expectation. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are "students" and student" different table? Or just typo?

Comment: I think you want to output the sum of min and max in the end result? Note that the `SUM` function sums an entire column. It does not compute the sum of two items in the same result record. You probably need `+` for that - may depend on your database.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could solve your problem

```
select min(marks)+max(marks) as total_marks from Students
```

Comment: tanx ...its wrking

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to get the maximum mark and minimum mark from Students table and finally sum the maximum mark and minimum mark.

If this your scenario below is the query which you can start with

```
SELECT maxMark+minMark TotalMark
FROM (SELECT max(marks) maxMark, min(marks) minMark 
        FROM students) t1
```

Let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: its show error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT id, sum(maxmark+minmark) AS summark FROM 
(SELECT id, max(marks) AS maxmark, min(marks) AS minmark FROM students ) as m
```

Comment: its double the marks by each row in each student mark like stu1 mark is 80 mean it will show stu1 mark is 160..its follow to each student

Comment: SELECT id, sum(maxmark+minmark) AS summark
FROM
(
  SELECT id, max(marks) AS maxmark, min(marks) AS minmark
  FROM students 
  

) as m                                                                                                            this query working